# tweaking django rest framework template

Tags: javascript, django, html, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to tweak the login function of the code here -

```
{% block userlinks %}
    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
        {% optional_logout request user %}
    {% else %}
        {% optional_login request %}
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

I want to have it, when logged in, to also display a value before "logout" as "dashboard" and have that reference another URL that's represented in django.

so it would look like this in the dropdown -

```
USER -
    - dashboard
    - logout
```

I thought it would be a matter of adding a line in the code like so -

```
{% block userlinks %}
    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
        <a href="#dashboard">Dashboard</a>
        {% optional_logout request user %}
    {% else %}
        {% optional_login request %}
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

This ends up making a separate value in the nav-bar however which I don't want.  How do I get it inline?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

/myapp/templatetags/internal_extras.py

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals, absolute_import
from django import template
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse, NoReverseMatch
from django.http import QueryDict
from django.utils import six
from django.utils.encoding import iri_to_uri
from django.utils.html import escape
from django.utils.safestring import SafeData, mark_safe
from django.utils.html import smart_urlquote
from rest_framework.compat import urlparse, force_text
import re

register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag
def my_logout(request, user):
    """
    Include a logout snippet if REST framework's logout view is in the URLconf.
    """
    try:
        logout_url = reverse('rest_framework:logout')
    except NoReverseMatch:
        return '<li class="navbar-text">{user}</li>'.format(user=user)

    snippet = """<li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
            {user}
            <b class="caret"></b>
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href='/dashboard'>Dashboard</a></li>
            <li><a href='{href}?next={next}'>Log out</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>"""

    return snippet.format(user=user, href=logout_url, next=escape(request.path))
```

Then in my HTML I had the following -

```
{% load internal_extras %}

{% if user.is_authenticated %}
    {% my_logout request user %}
{% else %}
    {% optional_login request %}
```

That did it.

Answer (score 1):

Below is the code that should work for you:

```
{% block userlinks %}
    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
        <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                {{ user }}
                <b class="caret"></b>
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#dashboard">Dashboard</a></li>
                <li>{% optional_logout request %}</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    {% else %}
        <li>{% optional_login request %}</li>
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

Please give me a feedback.

EDIT:

The link should be in a list item. I added the `<li>` tags.

Comment: you put me in the right direction.  I had to do some reverse engineering to get it and had to make a custom template tag using the code in the rest_framework templatetags.